# What is a term in the context of cmdliner?

Tags: command-line, ocaml

Cmdliner is an awesome tool to build command line applications in OCaml. However, [the entire documentation](https://erratique.ch/software/cmdliner/doc/tutorial.html) is explained around the word “term”. This makes it hard for me to understand the docs properly because I’m constantly thinking about what term refers to.
Because how generic and broad the term "term" is it's very hard to google it, so any explanation in context will be awesome. Even in the specific [page of the term](https://erratique.ch/software/cmdliner/doc/Cmdliner/Term/index.html) I could not find any specific explanation of what a term is

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the page to which you linked. Here's a quick summary: a term is a value of type `'a Cmdliner.Term.t`. Because of the `'a` type variable, this can be a value of any type at all. It's a value essentially wrapped up in a container provided by `Cmdliner.Term`.

To work with terms you have two functions: `const` and `app`. `const` wraps up any value of type `'a` into a term. Note that the wrapped value can be a function (as functions are values). `app` applies a wrapped function to a wrapped value and gives you back the result as a wrapped value.

The reason this is difficult to follow is that it really is completely abstract. You can use any type you like for `'a` (as long as you use it consistently), and you can apply any functions you like to such values (again as long as the types are correct).

I hope this helps. Someone with more (or any :-) experience with Cmdliner can probably be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I was looking for a more general definition. For example, imagine that I asked what is a lambda, then the answer I would expect is “just an anonymous function”. I’m familiar with the concepts of lifting and parametric types, but the soca give me the impression that “term” refers to some kind of general meaning that I am not familiar with. Maybe it is just they decided to use that terminology without any specific reason.